# Install Packages in Python 2.7 in Mac and use that instead of Python 2.6 packages

Tags: python, macos

So I just installed Python 2.7 in my Macbook Pro.

The problem is I installed virtualenvwrapper, pip, virtualenv and many other packages in Python 2.6 and the binaries are in /usr/local/bin.

What I want to do then is install the aforementioned packages for Python 2.7 and use them instead of the packages from Python 2.6.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install them in 2.7.

```
python2.7 setup.py install
```

Comment: so how does that work? I mean, won't they conflict with the already installed pip in /usr/local/bin? So whenever I do a pip install then the 2.6 package will be the one executed? Or will it also be done by python2.7 pip install?

Comment: As a note to anyone following this, like I was: the `pip-2.7` command may not be immediately available in shell sessions that already existed when `python2.7 setup.py install` was run, including the session in which the install was run, but it is available in any shell session started after that.